# Two same file names in Xcode project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to create a project utilizing both MailChimp and ShareKit code.

I believe I'm dynamically linking to them both by dragging their Xcode project files into my new project, then dragging and dropping the desired groups.

The problem I'm having now is that they both use a file name called SBJSonParser from their JSON libraries.

I'm getting an error that says:
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser

I don't want / don't think renaming the files would be sufficient, as there are quite a few more filenames they have in common. Does anyone have ideas on what to do? Thanks

Full error:

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PolaroidMe.app/PolaroidMe normal i386
    cd /Users/user/Documents/PolaroidMe
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Intermediates/PolaroidMe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PolaroidMe.build/Objects-normal/i386/PolaroidMe.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework CoreLocation -framework Twitter -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework MessageUI -framework AVFoundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PolaroidMe.app/PolaroidMe

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser in /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Intermediates/PolaroidMe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PolaroidMe.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonParser-7C0C46CE63D45CA3.o and /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Intermediates/PolaroidMe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PolaroidMe.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonParser-227BA1E6AFC01E91.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1


ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser in /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Intermediates/PolaroidMe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PolaroidMe.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonParser-7C0C46CE63D45CA3.o and /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PolaroidMe-gvmchgayobqfebhcnhfwhxoueaeo/Build/Intermediates/PolaroidMe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PolaroidMe.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonParser-227BA1E6AFC01E91.o for architecture i386
```

Comment: They're probably one and the same, so just delete one of them?

Comment: I don't think you are linking anything unless you added the library files to the linking phase of your target. To narrow the possible problem why don't you paste the full error message?

Comment: vakio: I looked at the files, they're different.


lawicko: I added the full error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBJSON is a library, it only needs to be inside your project once. Just delete one of them.

Comment: There were two filenames that conflicted: SBJsonParser and SBJsonWriter. The JSON folders also had some different files. I deleted the MailChimp ones, and it seems to be ok.